# Normalization of data in Excel from 0 to 1

Tags: excel, normalization

For my class we are learning normalization of data. My proffessor gave an example of how to do do it with the data below (first table below). But he didn't really show how to get the numbers of the second table in Excel. Can someone show me how he got those numbers? The numbers in the second table are from 0 to 1, where 0 is the wrost and 1 is the best.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBs1c.png
DRAW BEST TO WORST CHART ON BOARD – WITH LINEARY NORMALIZATION BETWEEN
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnmoP.png

Comment: this belongs on [su]

Answer (score 0):

To normalize you only need to divide by the greatest value in each column. Thus the biggest value will be equal to one.

Comment: From the images, it looks like the formula used is actually `1 - (value - minimum value) / (maximum value - minimum value)`, thus the smallest value becomes one and the largest value becomes zero.